# Is there something like Incanter for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, clojure, incanter

[Incanter](http://incanter.org) is an R-like library for Clojure. Is there anything like this for Haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various bits and pieces, but certainly no "platform". I think Haskell would be great for statistics and data visualization so it's a pity.

Some of the bits and pieces:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-gsl-stats
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart

And many others, but it's all very fragmented and disorganized.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even just having a list of packages to look at is better than grepping through hackage.

Comment: I also found http://hackage.haskell.org/package/csv-enumerator to be extremely useful for large CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

[There may be one soon...](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Mathematics-and-Statistics-libraries-td5583596.html)